# Random Number in a do-while loop with if statement

Tags: javascript, loops, random, do-while, do-loops

I am trying to get make a random number generator that generates a string of numbers between 1 and 9, and if it generates an 8, it should display the 8 last and then stop generating.

So far it prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, but it does not generate a random string of numbers, so I need to know how to make the loop actually generate random numbers as stated above, thanks for any help!

**Javascript**

```
// 5. BONUS CHALLENGE: Write a while loop that builds a string of random 
integers
// between 0 and 9. Stop building the string when the number 8 comes up.
// Be sure that 8 does print as the last character. The resulting string 
// will be a random length.
print('5th Loop:');
text = '';

// Write 5th loop here:
function getRandomNumber( upper ) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;
  return num;

}
i = 0;
do {
  i += 1;

    if (i >= 9) {
      break;
    }
  text += i + ' ';
} while (i <= 9);


print(text); // Should print something like `4 7 2 9 8 `, or `9 0 8 ` or `8 
`.
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7) + 1` is your friend.

Comment: Your logic looks flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a more simply way:

The solution is to `push` the random generated number into one array and then use `join` method in order to **join** all elements of the array the string desired.

```js
function getRandomNumber( upper ) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;
  return num;
}
var array = [];
do { 
  random = getRandomNumber(9);
  array.push(random);
} while(random != 8)
console.log(array.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not because it's better, but because we can (and I like generators :) ), an alternative with an iterator function (ES6 required):

```js
function* getRandomNumbers() {
  for(let num;num !==8;){
    num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);   
    yield num;    
  }
}

let text= [...getRandomNumbers()].join(' ');
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

print() is a function which goal is to print a document, you should use console.log() to display in console.

Put a boolean before your loop, for example `var eightAppear = false`

Your condition now look like `do {... }while(!eightAppear)`

Then inside your loop generate a random number between 0 and 9. `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)`
Concat your string. If number is 8 change value of `eightAppear` to `true`

Since it seem to be an exercise, i'll let you code it, should not be hard now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to accomplish this. Here I'm creating a variable i and storing the random number in it, then I create the while loop.

```
i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
while (i !== 8) {
  text += i + ' ';
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}
  text += i;

console.log(text);
```

Here is the same thing but as a do...while loop.

```
i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
do {
  text += i + ' ';
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
} while (i !== 8)
  text += i;
console.log(text);
```